# If entropy is positive, then why do stars form from nebulae?

Tags: stars, nebulae

Sorry if I have so many misconceptions with this questions, but I guess that's the point of asking questions.

If entropy, the measure of disorder, is always positive, then how come a star could form from a nebula?

Considering that a nebula is made of debris of a planet/star, this proves that entropy is positive. But now that it "reforms" as another star, isn't the level of "disorder" decreasing?

Comment: Edit: I assumed that entropy is positive when a planet/star collapses because energy is released, and the particles/matter gets scattered.

Comment: I think what you mean is *change* in entropy. And the entropy of one part of the universe can go down, as long as the entropy of some other part of the universe goes up by *at least* the amount by which the first part went down. The statement of the Second Law is "In an *isolated system*, entropy never decreases." Isolated means that the system can exchange no energy with any other system, but nebulae can clearly lose and gain mass, absorb and emit radiation, etc., so they are decidedly not isolated.